# How to avoid sideEffects when using React useState?

Tags: reactjs

My app behaves weirdly and I found out it goes away when I remove useState in one of my functions. However, I need to use the useState function.

So I am creating a ToDo app where one can add, edit and delete a ToDo Task. Everything works fine except when I want to edit an existing ToDo Task. When I click the edit Button, **nothing happens the first time**. Only on the second click does the Task change to the edit mode!

```
const [editme, setEditme] = useState(false)


  function edit(e){
    const editingItem = list.filter(obj => obj.id == e);
    const el = document.getElementById('myInput')
    el.value = editingItem[0].item

    // --- this gets me in TROUBLE --- //
    setEditme(true)
    // ------------------------------- //
  }

      <ul>
        {list.map((item)=>{
          return(
            <div className="li-all">
            <li key={item.id}>{item.item}</li><div className="li-right"><FaPen onClick={()=>edit(item.id)}/><FaTrash onClick={()=>del(item.id)}/></div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
```

Comment: `el.value = editingItem[0].item` should not be done in React, use state instead...

Comment: Yes, certainPerformance is right. Keep everything about your todos in `useState`. And if you see `getElementById` in your code that's probably not right. The only place where you'll see it is at `index.js`. Please have a look at the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-todo-app-0ed0p) to get an idea of how you could do it. If it is getting more complex, `useReducer` is something to check

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks a ton. It helped me out.

Comment: @AWolf Thanks buddy. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So both CertainPerformance and AWolf are correct. You should never directly manipulate the DOM in React. Use useState and let React figure it out how it wants to render it.

In my case, I was trying to copy a ToDo Item `(List Item <li>)` directly into the Input Form to allow users to edit the Item.

**WRONG** `( <li> -> <input>)`

```
  function edit(e){

    const editingItem = list.filter(obj => obj.id == e);
    const el = document.getElementById('myInput')

    // WRONG //
    el.value = editingItem[0].item
    // ---- //

    setEditme(true)
  }
```

The correct way is set it to state and the using state to pass it where you need. Seem counter-intuitive but in essence you are letting React figure out how to best render the frontend.

**CORRECT** `( <li> -> getState/useState -> <input>)`

```
  function edit(e){

    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const editingItem = list.filter(obj => obj.id == e);
    const el = document.getElementById('myInput')

    // CORRECT //
    setValue(editingItem[0].item)
    el.value = value
    // ---- //

    setEditme(true)
  }
```